Building Qt on Windows, problem with EGL/ECM
Trying to build Qt on Windows. I've downloaded and unpacked the big source archive, qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0, but CMake gives a bunch of error messages regarding the configuration of a module that seems to be called EGL or ECM. Any ideas?
C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0>md build

C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0>cd build

C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0\build>cmake .. -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\Qt\6.7.0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtbase'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtimageformats'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlanguageserver'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtshadertools'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtsvg'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdeclarative'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquicktimeline'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquick3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtmultimedia'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qt3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qt5compat'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtactiveqt'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtcharts'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtcoap'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtconnectivity'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdatavis3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtgraphs'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebsockets'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qthttpserver'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtserialport'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtpositioning'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlocation'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qttools'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebchannel'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebengine'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdoc'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtgrpc'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlottie'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtmqtt'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtnetworkauth'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtopcua'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquick3dphysics'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquickeffectmaker'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtremoteobjects'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtscxml'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtsensors'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtserialbus'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtspeech'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qttranslations'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtvirtualkeyboard'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwayland'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebview'
-- Configuring submodule 'qtbase'
-- [QtBase] CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE was already explicitly set to: 'Release'
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=/Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=/O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=/Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=/Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=/O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=/Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=/machine:x64
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=11
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0/qtbase/cmake/platforms
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/FindEGL.cmake:63 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0/qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/ECMFindModuleHelpersStub.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:156 (find_package)
  qtbase/src/gui/configure.cmake:36 (qt_find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:678 (include)
  qtbase/src/CMakeLists.txt:13 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/FindEGL.cmake:67 (ecm_find_package_version_check):
  Unknown CMake command "ecm_find_package_version_check".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:156 (find_package)
  qtbase/src/gui/configure.cmake:36 (qt_find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:678 (include)
  qtbase/src/CMakeLists.txt:13 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The above omits configure.bat but calling it, gives the same results:
C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0>md build

C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0>cd build

C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0\build>..\configure.bat
+ cd qtbase
+ C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0\qtbase\configure.bat -top-level
The system cannot find the drive specified.
The system cannot find the drive specified.
-- Windows 10 SDK version: 10.0.22000.0
'C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '-DQT_INTERNAL_CALLED_FROM_CONFIGURE:BOOL=TRUE' '-G' 'Ninja' 'C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0'
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.39.33523.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is MSVC
-- Found assembler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtbase'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtimageformats'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlanguageserver'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtshadertools'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtsvg'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdeclarative'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquicktimeline'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquick3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtmultimedia'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qt3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qt5compat'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtactiveqt'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtcharts'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtcoap'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtconnectivity'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdatavis3d'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtgraphs'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebsockets'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qthttpserver'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtserialport'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtpositioning'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlocation'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qttools'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebchannel'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebengine'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtdoc'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtgrpc'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtlottie'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtmqtt'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtnetworkauth'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtopcua'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquick3dphysics'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtquickeffectmaker'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtremoteobjects'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtscxml'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtsensors'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtserialbus'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtspeech'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qttranslations'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtvirtualkeyboard'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwayland'
-- Checking dependencies of submodule 'qtwebview'
-- Configuring submodule 'qtbase'
-- [QtBase] Setting build type to 'Release' as none was specified.
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=/Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=/O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=/Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /EHsc
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=/Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=/O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO=/Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG
            -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=/machine:x64
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=11
            -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
            -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED=ON
            -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0/qtbase/cmake/platforms
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/FindEGL.cmake:63 (include):
  include could not find requested file:

    C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0/qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/ECMFindModuleHelpersStub.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:156 (find_package)
  qtbase/src/gui/configure.cmake:36 (qt_find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:678 (include)
  qtbase/src/CMakeLists.txt:13 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/3rdparty/extra-cmake-modules/find-modules/FindEGL.cmake:67 (ecm_find_package_version_check):
  Unknown CMake command "ecm_find_package_version_check".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtFindPackageHelpers.cmake:156 (find_package)
  qtbase/src/gui/configure.cmake:36 (qt_find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtFeature.cmake:678 (include)
  qtbase/src/CMakeLists.txt:13 (qt_feature_evaluate_features)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0/qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:1077 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.

And:
C:\qt-everywhere-src-6.7.0\build>cmake --version
cmake version 3.28.0-msvc1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).      


What version of CMake are you using? Have you followed the Qt Build instructions? It seems to me that you haven't executed the configure.bat.

@m7913d Reasonable questions! Edited to add answers.

I'm not familiar with your particular issue, but I went down a rabbit hole of getting Qt6 installed from source from this forum post

Do you have any hard set limitations on the type of build system you are using? Such as it has to be this build tool set or compiler?
